# Is it possible to use iOS Charts (Daniel Gindi) to generate graphs in pdf document on iOS

Tags: pdf, ios-charts

I am using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) (Daniel Gindi) to generate graphs in an iOS app and I want to be able to generate a PDF report with those graphs included in the body of the report.  Can anyone explain how to go about doing this.  Ideally I don't want to generate an image from the UIView that shows in the app because the size/resolution would not be suitable for the PDF document.

As I understand it there are a few options:

1. use the graphics context for the pdf document to draw the graph on - it's not clear whether this would be possible when using the Charts library

   2. use a UIView somehow to generate the graph and generate a PDF image data from that, embed this image into the pdf report

It seems like option 1 is probably the preferred way to get best resolution/control - somewhat speculative - doing it this way means you should be able to specify the exact position and size and get the correct font sizes, line thicknesses, etc..

Using option 2 means you have to figure out the scaling between a UIView and the PDF page view and I am not sure how these would map to each other.

Can anyone provide any suggestions on the following:

1. Is it possible to use Charts to generate graphs in a PDF document, and if so how?
2. If not what other options are there, short of writing custom drawing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so here is what I have done

**Option 1:  Using a UIView.layer to render on the PDF CGContect**

```
func drawLineGraph(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)->CGRect{

    let width = (pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset)/2.0 - 50.0

    let renderingRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y + 50.0, width: width, height: 150.0)

    // Create a view for the Graph
    let graphController = LineChartController(rect: renderingRect, building: self.building)

    if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

        let frame = graphController.chartView.frame
        currentContext.saveGState()
        currentContext.translateBy(x:frame.origin.x, y:frame.origin.y);
        graphController.chartView.layer.render(in: currentContext)
        currentContext.restoreGState()
    }
    return renderingRect
}
```

The `graphController` is just an object that has essentially the same function as the usual parent `ViewController` that would contain the graph.  Sets the graph parameters and data.

Once that has been done the function below is called to render on the PDF page context.

A bit of translation required to put the graphs in the correct position.

**Option 2:  Drawing on the PDF Page CGContect**

And the solution is...ta da...

```
func drawBarGraph(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)->CGRect{

        let width = (pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset)/2.0 - 50.0

        let renderingRect = CGRect(x: x + width + 50, y: y + 50.0, width: width, height: 150.0)

        // Create a view for the Graph
        let graphController = BarChartController(rect: renderingRect, building: self.building)

        if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

            let frame = graphController.chartView.frame
            currentContext.saveGState()
            currentContext.translateBy(x:frame.origin.x, y:frame.origin.y)

            //graphController.chartView.layer.render(in: currentContext)
            graphController.chartView.draw(frame)

            currentContext.restoreGState()   

        }
        return renderingRect
    }
```

Since the current context is set to the PDF page's context just call the charts `draw()` function directly passing the frame rectangle.

What have I missed here, can it be this easy ?

You can find a copy of the [generated PDF here as well as sample code](https://ossh.com.au/adding-charts-to-pdf-output/).

Comment: but how it will bind the data ? r u sure its generating pdf with data in graph ?

Comment: If I knew how to attach a pdf to my answer I would attach the output.  I will attach a png with zoomed in view so you can see for yourself.  The graphController provides the data source.  I will post the controller class as well for completeness.

Comment: @CodeChanger - I have updated my answer with a link to the generated PDF file - you can check it out yourself.  I will post more of the code at some point.